Connect to Cloud SQL from Google Kubernetes Engine - dial tcp: lookup sqladmin.googleapis.com: i/o timeout
Our application is running in GKE and I am using Cloud Proxy as a sidecar to connect to the database. After new release one pod shown up 2 restart when I check the container restart was for cloud-sqlproxy container.
When I looked into logs then found an error

"textPayload": "\tGet "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/GCP_PROJECT_NAME/instances/europe-west2~SQL_INSTANCE_NAME/connectSettings?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": dial tcp: lookup sqladmin.googleapis.com: i/o timeout"

I guess Cloud SQL proxy tried to set up connection with DB using API that is sqladmin.googleapis.com but it ran into timeout.
I am looking for information on how I can force a cloud-sqlproxy sidecar to retry connection in case of timeout.

Possibly related: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-go-connector/issues/718.

How are you launching the Proxy? And what version are you using?

Hello @enocom,
I am using https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/iam-logins and Cloud proxy is container is part of application deployment descriptor with ISTIO Service mesh.
We are using gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.33.0-buster
I am sure I am not seeing any issue like "Failed to get instance metadata" it was only specific to dial tcp: lookup sqladmin.googleapis.com: i/o timeout
